# Reading excel variable into power shell and outputting it

Tags: powershell

I am tring to read out a excel cell and outputting it into Powershell, however it does not work.
Can somebody help me with this?

Code:

```
$path = "Pfad"
#$csv = Import-Csv -path $path
$xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"

$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($path)
   
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)
   
$rownum = 1
$columnnum = 1


$csvpfad = $ws.Cells.Item(1, 1).Value

write-host $csvpfad
```

When I try to output it, it does say:
Variant Value (Variant) {get} {set}

I am a complete newby so hopefully you excus my missing knowlegde

BR

Comment: Try `.Value()` or `.Value(10)` instead of just `.Value`

Answer (score 0):

For a property, what you're looking for is `Value2`

For methods, what Mathias suggested both also work `.Value()` or `.Value(10)`

```
$ws.Cells.Item(1, 1).Value2
```

You can update the cell using the same property name

```
$ws.Cells.Item(1, 1).Value2 = "Some New Value"
```

You can take each variable/item and inspect it with `Get-Member`. Powershell is pretty good about only showing the members of the first item of a similar collection, but with com objects it's not as easy. So you can specify the first item and then pass it

```
$ws.Cells | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Member
```

You'll see all the different methods and properties of the Cells object. You can add `-Force` to see more details.

```
$ws.Cells | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Member -Force
```